# Spring Boot - relationship deleted on save() method

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

My problem is this: There is a many to many relationship between two tables - Project and Employee. There is an option to update a given employee, but there is a little problem. After updating the employee, hibernate automatically deletes the employee's record from the connected project_employee table.

> Hibernate: update employee set email=?, first_name=?, last_name=? where employee_id=?

And this happens right after that

> Hibernate: delete from project_employee where employee_id=?

I'm following a course and I've just noticed this error. Source code of the lecturer is here:

https://github.com/imtiazahmad007/spring-framework-course

Comment: Please, share your entity model. Delete may be cascaded, if you misconfigured collections.

Comment: Can you try instantiating the lists as new ArrayLists?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your github page:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST},
           fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="project_employee",
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="employee_id"),
inverseJoinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="project_id")
        )
@JsonIgnore
private List<Project> projects;
```

CascadeType.MERGE + CascadeType.PERSIST mean, that if Employee entity is saved, Project entity references must be saved.

In may-to-many cases it means:

- DELETE by foreign key
- Bulk insert

In case there's no bulk insert, there's an issue with persisntence context (your are saving an entity with empty collection of projects).

Possible solutions:

- Remove CascadeType.MERGE + CascadeType.PERSIST if you do not want to change projects every time your save Employee. You can still save the ccollection via Repository
- Make sure collection is attached on save action. That will cause Delete+Insert, but the resut will be ok.
- Change Many-To-Many to One-To-Many with EmbeddedId

Please, refer to documentation:

When an entity is removed from the @ManyToMany collection, Hibernate simply deletes the joining record in the link table. Unfortunately, this operation requires removing all entries associated with a given parent and recreating the ones that are listed in the current running persistent context.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many

*** Update from dialog below to make cascade clear.

Say, you have two entities A & B (getters and setters omitted). + repos

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinTable(name="a_b",
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="a_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="b_id")
  )
  private List<B> bs;
  
 }

@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B {

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  private String name;
  
 }
```

You sample test looks like this:

```
  @Test
  public void testSave() {
    B b = new B();
    b.setId(1);
    b.setName("b");
    b = bRepository.save(b);

    A a = new A();
    a.setId(1);
    a.setName("a");
    a.setBs(Collections.singletonList(b));
    aRepository.save(a);

    a.setName("new");
    service.save(a); //watch sevice implementations below
  }
```

Version1:

```
  @Transactional
  public void save(A a) {
    aRepository.save(a);
  }
```

Hibernate logs are the following:

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        a 
    set
        name=? 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        a_b 
    where
        a_id=?
Hibernate:
    insert 
    into
        a_b
        (a_id, b_id) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

delete+bulk insert present (despite the fact, that B-s where not in fact changed)

Version2:

```
  @Transactional
  public void save(A a) {
    Optional<A> existing = aRepository.findById(a.getId());
    if (existing.isPresent()) {
     a.setBs(existing.get().getBs());
    }
    aRepository.save(a);
  }
```

Logs:

```
update
    a 
set
    name=? 
where
    id=?
```

Here b-collection was forcibly re-attached, so hibernate understands, that it's not needed to be cascaded.

Comment: Wouldn't annotating the `partialUpdate` function with `@Transactional` also work? Or is that what you mean by "Make sure collection is attached on save action. That will cause Delete+Insert, but the resut will be ok."

Comment: @PaulD, transactions have noting to do with cascade rules. Basicly, Spring will open a transaction, even if you did not provide this anno (but transaction borders will be different). By keeping an attached collection I meant a common case: user sends an update request with a set of fields, but omits the cascade-collection (it's missing in API or is not supposed to be updated). Obviosly, the collection is deleted.  It's a design bug. On service level it would mean that following is required: fetch entity, map/propagate user changes, call save.

Comment: the only reason I see for the collection to be deleted is that its a persistent bag that has not been fetched and as we leave the transaction context of finding the entity, the projects get interpreted as an empty collection. I am unsure what you mean. The user sends an object without the collection, but the object isn't the one being saved, only some of the values are being mapped to the database object.

Comment: @PaulD, the collection will be deleted by design (see documentation). Afterwards it's supposed to be inserted, if it was fetched (or, say, not empty). It was not fetched, so items were not inserted back. Moreover, hibernate doesn't map some values to db objects: it mappes all plain fields and all collections with cascade options. You can't partially update an object via save in repo, unless they are exlicitly marked as updatable =false in entity.

Comment: I have am issue with the part of the documentation you are referencing because it has nothing to do with the actual problem, the deletion of the whole collection is not a result of one entry being removed from the collection and then triggering a full reinsert, the problem is that the whole collection is empty, because it hasn't been fetched. Adding a transaction would make it much easier to fetch the collection by simply calling `Employee#getProjects()` after finding the `Employee` entity, although that might not be necessary as the entity isnt detached anymore after finding it.

Comment: @PaulD, your point with attached collection is valid, I've provided answer with samples of behaviour with attached&detached collections.